# how to get response from axios with multiable objects?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I am getting  response payload from server like this:

```
{"0":
[
{"id":1,
  "profile_id":"1",
  "schoolName":"xx",
  "courseName":"xx",
  "courseDescription":null,      
  "created_at":"2020-06-25T09:11:21.000000Z",
  "updated_at":"2020-06-25T09:11:21.000000Z"},
{"id":2,
  "profile_id":"1",
  "schoolName":"yy",
  "courseName":"zz",
  "courseDescription":"xx",      
  "created_at":null,
  "updated_at":null}
],  
"status":"Read Education info successfully!"}
```

- Axios .then response is like this:

  .then((response)=>{
  vm.setState (
  { educations: Object.values(response.data) },
  () => console.log(this.state.datas)
  );
  })
- data- object has educations: []- array inside multiable

education: -objects

Q)  how to pass axios response data payload to education object?,

```
export default {
data() {
    return {
    educations: [
     education: {}],
```

--- Edit ---
Tried to get response like this:

```
   .then((response)=>{
        this.education = response.data.map(value => {
          return {
            schoolName: value.schoolName,
            courseName: value.courseName
          }
          console.log('Receiving data ....')
        })
```

Vue does not give any error, but I cannot see any data to pass data-object.
In Vuestools:
education : object
courseName: "" is empty.

---

Comment: Can i see your backend endpoint function?

Comment: here is api.php: Route::get('education/{pid}/index', 'EducationController@index')->name('education.perProfile');      Education@index:   
     public function index($id)
    {
    if ($education = Education::where('profile_id', $id)->get()){
      return response()->json([
      $education,
          'status' => 'Read Education info successfully!',
      ], 201);